# Elisions are not supported error using newman to run integration tests

Tags: node.js, json, postman

I'm using Postman and the CLI tool Newman to run integration tests against several microservices.

I've had to refactor a fair bit of it recently, and my latest test run throws an error from Newman:

```
> newman run Postman.postman_collection.json -e ../postman_environments/Integration.postman_environment.json --env-var authorization="$TOKEN"
error: Elisions are not supported at 25:4
        ,
         ^
```

I've searched for this error message considerably, but can't seem to find any results pertaining to postman or newman, or vaguely related to software whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched StackOverflow and haven't found this, so I figured I'd answer my own question. A couple of pages into Google search results, I found an [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas) article mentioning `elisions`:

`{in Arrays and Objects} If more than one trailing comma is used, an elision (or hole) is produced.`

It turns out that I had an extra comma in the `Integration.postman_environment.json` file! Presumably, this error is thrown by a `JSON.parse()` call inside of `newman`.

Since I was totally unable to find this answer on SO, I decided to answer my own question.

Comment: It's good that you answered your own question .

Comment: ha! Well, hopefully I've helped you or someone else